# How to send an object to ActiveMQ (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, activemq-classic

I am trying to send an object (Ex: `StudentModel with ID, Name, Address,..)` to `ActiveMQ`, I have read many tutorials but not much for c#. I followed a tutorial and it does not work. Here is my code in send form:

```cs
    Person p = new Person(123, "vtp", new DateTime(1999, 11, 01));
    IObjectMessage m = session.CreateObjectMessage(p);
    producer.Send(m);
```

In receive form:

```cs
    private void Consumer_Listener(IMessage message)
    {
        if (message is IObjectMessage)
        {            
            IObjectMessage obj = message as IObjectMessage; //1
            Person p = (Person)obj.Body; //2
            MessageBox.Show(p.Hoten); //3
         }
    }
```

I debug and realize that the code only repeat at statements 1 and 2, not runs at statement 3

Comment: You are almost certainly getting an Exception. I suspect the `Body` cannot be cast directly to a `Person`.  Use exception handling to determine the error. What is the format/content of `obj.Body`?

Comment: [This looks old](https://activemq.apache.org/components/nms/msdoc/1.6.0/vs2005/Output/html/M_Apache_NMS_MessageExtensions_ToObject%60%601_1_2d6dd840.htm) and might not be the library you are using, but if it is try the `ToObject<T>` method instead of casting.

Comment: I use try catch and it shows error: Unable to find assembly 'frmSender', version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PulicKeyToken=null'. Do i have to format obj. Body first ?

Comment: That is not at all the error I was expecting. I assume `frmSender` is one of your Forms? I honestly don't know how that error could possible relate to that line of code. Are you showing the actual code you are running or have you abridged it for the question?

Comment: I have also just become unclear if you are saying line //2 runs without error and moves on to //3 or if the error happens while executing line //2. Can you confirm which line actually blows up?

Comment: frmSender is used for send message. I debug and here is how it runs: 1->2->1->2->1->2 and out, not moves on to //3. Use try { //1 //2 //3} and catch the error like that.

Comment: I have two form: frmSender (Send message), frmRecive (Receive message) and 
located in different projects

Answer (score 0):

Serialized ObjectMessage style messaging with ActiveMQ is really intended for Java based clients.  Using the .NET specific ObjectMessage is a risky proposition and should be avoided in almost all cases.  If any Java clients were to be consuming those messages the binary payload of the .NET Objects would cause them to be unable to unmarshal the payload and they would NACK the message to the DLQ.  Similarly if the broker had a plugin installed that happened to trigger an unmarshal of the message body the process would fail and the message would likely either go the DLQ or the connection would be dropped.

You should consider some other form of payload serialization such as JSON payloads in a TextMessage or a manual binary encode into a BytesMessage which would at least not cause non .NET clients to fail outright on the message itself.